# Code formatting issues

Tags: support, code-formatting

Please see this question:
[How to use transparent image in WinCe 5.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118717/how-to-use-transparent-image-in-wince-5-0/41161245#41161245)

I've tried everything I can think of for the code to show up as normal.

Comment: Indent by an extra 4 spaces inside lists

Comment: Why 5 downvotes? Knowing that the question marked as a duplicate really was a duplicate is surely only obvious if you know that the problem is having code within a list! I'll chalk this up to experience...

Answer (score 2):

@PatrickHoffman already edited for you.  All you had to do was indent all your code with 4 spaces.

As a general rule, when you see that someone is able to apply a feature in their post that you are unable to reproduce, my recommendation is simply go to a post where the results you are seeking show up; click edit, see how they did it, and then cancel the edit and apply the principle to your post.  It's worked wonders for me.

Comment: The code was indented with 4 spaces both manually and using the recommended CTRL+K shortcut. The added advice to `use an extra 4 spaces` is not immediately obvious nor was the fact that the problem was related to having code within a list. Thanks for the comments.